# SetInterval is causing update state variables to default values in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, setinterval

I am trying to get the values( say X ) from my database and display a new random number from range (X+2), (X-2) every 3 seconds.

**Default Values Are**

```
//in Reducer (Initial State)
cprice : {
     "available":50,
     "taken" : 0,
     "total" : 50,
     "price" : 50
 }
```

**Values from Database are**

```
    cprice : {
        "available":50,
        "taken" : 0,
        "total" : 50,
        "price" : 70
    }
```

But when I run my code, I think SetInterval rerenders the component and make the cprice to default values. Heres my code :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    startGetCPrice()
  }, [])                 <= gets new values for cprice

  const [currentCPrice, setCurrrentCPrice] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
      window.setInterval(() => {
        console.log(cprice.price)        <--- cprice.price is 50 here
        setCurrrentCPrice(currentCPrice => randomCPrice(cprice.price));
      },3000)
  },[])

  console.log(currentCPrice); <--- currentCPrice is random number near 50 here
  let randomCPrice = (crpt) => {
    console.log(crpt)                  <--- cprt is 50 here
    return Math.random()*4 + crpt -2 ;
  }
  console.log( cprice.price) <--- cprice.price is 70 here
```

I am getting random numbers near 50, but I want random numbers near the value in my database updated every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your useEffect callback is called at the first render only (when currentCPrice is default) meaning the previous state in setCurrrentCPrice is not up to date

this should fix your issue

```
useEffect(() => {
      const interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        console.log(cprice.price)        <--- cprice.price is 50 here
        setCurrrentCPrice(currentCPrice => randomCPrice(cprice.price));
      },3000)
      return ()=> clearInterval(interval)
},[setCurrrentCPrice])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Your answer pointed me in the right direction.
I implemented your code, still got the same result.
I then replaced  `setCurrentCPrice` with `cprice.price` in the dependency array and got the desired outcome.